# Setting and using maxAge with react-cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set a cookie that expires after a period of time in React using the react-cookie npm package. I'm following the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie

I have the following code:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import DashboardNav from "./dashboard-nav";
import "./App.css";

function Dashboard() {
    const [ cookies, setCookie ] = useCookies([['cookie-name']]);

    setCookie('session', true, { maxAge: 1000 });

    console.log(cookies);

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(cookies);
    }, 1500);
    
    return (
        <DashboardNav />
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I set the cookie to expire after 1000 milliseconds and set a setTimeout function to print the cookie after 1500 milliseconds. I thought it would print out undefined, as maxAge is set to 1000 when setting the cookie, but I must be mistaken. To reiterate, I need to be able to set a cookie to expire, and be able to detect that expiration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks